# "ionic build android" on windows 8.1 64-bit: Error: Hook failed with error code ENOENT

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am following http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/
When I run

```
ionic build android
```

I have following error:

```
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
running cordova build android
Running command: C:\Windows\system32\node C:\_Learn\ionic\firstIonicApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\_Learn\ionic\firstIonicApp
Error: Hook failed with error code ENOENT: C:\_Learn\ionic\firstIonicApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js
    at C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:195:23
    at _rejected (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:797:24)
    at C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:741:41)
    at C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
```

My Android Home:

C:\>echo %ANDROID_HOME%

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is an open issue on Github](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/417#issuecomment-103531954)

And the workaround that I am using is just rename the **after_prepare** folder

Comment: Rename to what?@ToolKit

Comment: to some random name. i.e. ignore it. They couldn't fix it. Are you having this issue now?